# Connecting to ISP Modem/Router interface from secondary router connected through WAN to the first one

Tags: networking, router, administrator, wan

I have the following network, see picture

Network topology
[image]

What I want is to access the admin interface of router A from computer 1.

What should I read about, or what should I do?

Comment: I don't understand. Theoretically you should be able to access the admin page of A from computer 1 out-of-the-box (assuming you kept NAT on B intact).

Answer (score 0):

You have created two subnets in a fairly simple network by using the WAN port of the second router.

The following always works for me:

Connect a LAN port on the second router to a LAN port on router A.

Give the second router a Static IP on router A.

Turn DHCP OFF on the second router.

Now restart your routers and the computer will be able to access router A.